# Concatenate third party element while xml serialization

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have to serialize an XML structure in the following manner:

```html
<Toy>
  <Parameters>
     <!-- to be filled up by a 3rd-party function that delivers in string format -->
     <!-- the string format contains all the relevant XML tags --> 
     <!-- has the following format -->
     <!-- <Parameter> ........ </Parameter> <Parameter> ........ </Parameter> --> 
     <!-- is basically may be an element or array of elements from 3rd party with Parameter tag -->
  </Parameters>
    .
    .
    .
    .
</Toy>
```

I am following the reference  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer?view=netframework-4.6.1

This 3rd party XML contents is also dynamic , it may contain Array/Scalar/Boolean value , but it is definite that this 3rd party contents will reside inside "Node" element and All elements inside the "Node" element may contain several or no "Parameter" element

How to attach this 3rd party contents to the existing XML serialization process ?

I tried to achieve it in the following way as follows with tips from @Charles :

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
  public class Toy
  {
    [XmlArray(IsNullable = true)]
    public XmlElement[] Parameters { get; set; }

    public string Bar { get; set; }
  }
  
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {

    var xmlStringList = new List<string>();

    xmlStringList.Add("<Parameter><Scalar>5</Scalar></Parameter>");
    xmlStringList.Add("<Parameter><Scalar>50</Scalar></Parameter>");
    xmlStringList.Add("<Parameter><Scalar><Alu>67</Alu></Scalar></Parameter>");

    var doc = new XmlDocument();

    var elementList = new List<XmlElement>();

    foreach (var xmlItem in xmlStringList)
    {
        doc.LoadXml(xmlItem);
        elementList.Add(doc.DocumentElement);
    }

    var toy = new Toy
    {
        Parameters = elementList.ToArray(),
        Bar = "2"
    };

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Toy));
    serializer.Serialize(Console.Out,toy);
  }
}
```

But the outcome was not as expected

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Codepage - 850"?>
<Toy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Parameters>
    <XmlElement>
      <Parameter>
        <Scalar>5</Scalar>
      </Parameter>
    </XmlElement>
    <XmlElement>
      <Parameter>
        <Scalar>50</Scalar>
      </Parameter>
    </XmlElement>
    <XmlElement>
      <Parameter>
        <Scalar>
          <Alu>67</Alu>
        </Scalar>
      </Parameter>
    </XmlElement>
  </Parameters>
  <Bar>2</Bar>
</Toy>
```

the XmLElement tag is not expected to have in the output. Anyway to remove it? The expected output is:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Codepage - 850"?>
<Toy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Parameters>    
      <Parameter>
        <Scalar>5</Scalar>
      </Parameter>        
      <Parameter>
        <Scalar>50</Scalar>
      </Parameter>        
      <Parameter>
        <Scalar>
          <Alu>67</Alu>
        </Scalar>
      </Parameter>    
  </Parameters>
  <Bar>2</Bar>
</Toy>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a property of type `XmlElement` and load your XML string into that DOM. This will be serialised correctly.

So you can load your XML like this:

```cs
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlString);
var node = doc.DocumentElement;
```

And then add a property to your model:

```cs
public class Toy
{
    public XmlElement Node { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gDiRRS) for a working demo.

Comment: getting exception if the 3rd party string contains as follows: 

const string xmlString = @"<Foo>1</Foo><Foo>10</Foo>";

Comment: That's not a valid XML element, it's multiple elements. If, as you say, everything should be wrapped in `Node`, then the easiest thing to do here is to wrap that string: `<Node><Foo>1</Foo><Foo>10</Foo></Node>`.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I got the following work-around, still looking for a better solution:

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

public class Program
{
  public class Toy
  {
    public string Bar { get; set; }
  }
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var toy = new Toy
    {
        Bar = "2"
    };

    var streamWriter = File.CreateText("toy.xml");

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Toy));
    serializer.Serialize(streamWriter, toy);

    streamWriter.Close();

    var xmlStringList = new List<string>();

    xmlStringList.Add("<Parameters>");
    xmlStringList.Add("<Parameter><Scalar>5</Scalar></Parameter>");
    xmlStringList.Add("<Parameter><Scalar>50</Scalar></Parameter>");
    xmlStringList.Add("<Parameter><Scalar><Alu>67</Alu></Scalar></Parameter>");
    xmlStringList.Add("</Parameters>");

    

    var concatXml = string.Concat(xmlStringList.ToArray());


    var doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("toy.xml");

    var xmlDocFragment = doc.CreateDocumentFragment();
    xmlDocFragment.InnerXml = concatXml;

    doc.SelectSingleNode("Toy").AppendChild(xmlDocFragment);

    doc.Save("toy.xml");        
    
  }
}
```